# Trying to bind GridView from Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, gridview

So I have a DataSet which is populated from an XML file, from which I'm trying to populate a GridView using LINQ. But the GridView is rendering empty. Here is the code-behind...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinqSamples samples = new LinqSamples(gvNumbers, this.Page);
    samples.DataSetLinq40();
}

private class LinqSamples
{
    private DataSet testDS;
    private GridView _gv;
    private Page _pg;

    public LinqSamples(GridView gv, Page pg)
    {
        testDS = TestHelper.CreateTestDataSet(pg);
        _gv = gv;
        _pg = pg;
    }

    public void DataSetLinq40()
    {
        var numbers = testDS.Tables["Numbers"].AsEnumerable();

        //var numberGroups = from n in numbers
        //                   group n by n.Field<int>("number") % 5 into g
        //                   select new { Remainder = g.Key, Numbers = g };

        //var justNums = from n in numbers
        //              select n;
        _gv.DataSource = justNums;
        _gv.DataBind();
    }
}

internal static DataSet CreateTestDataSet(Page pg)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    // Customers Table
    ds.Tables.Add(CreateNumbersTable());

    ds.AcceptChanges();
    return ds;
}

private static DataTable CreateNumbersTable()
{
    int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };
    DataTable table = new DataTable("Numbers");
    table.Columns.Add("number", typeof(int));
    foreach (int n in numbers)
    {
         table.Rows.Add(new object[] { n });
    }
    return table;
}
```

...and the .aspx page...

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvNumbers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
</asp:GridView>
```

Neither numberGroups nor justNums works, both result in an empty GridView.

Comment: What happens if you try to bind a collection of simple objects in the Form Load?  I.E. create something like var test = new List<Person>(); where person has Name, Age, Race, and then new up a few people, pump it into the list, and do the databind to the list?  Does anything show up?  If not, your issue is with binding to the datagrid, nowhere else.

Comment: Ok, good test, let me see...

Comment: You have "autogeneratecolumns" set to false - are you manually creating your columns anywhere in your code behind?

Comment: You hit upon the problem, mikrose, I added a boundfield in the GridView and it's working.